# Memory allocation Nvidia vs AMD

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia, amd-processor

I know there is a 128MB limit for a single block of GPU memory on AMD GPU's. Is there a similar limit on Nvidia GPU's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On GTX 560 `clGetDeviceInfo` returns 256MiB for CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE, however I can allocate slightly less than 1GiB. See [this thread](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=183786) discussing the issue.

On AMD however this limit is enforced. You can raise it by changing GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE and GPU_MAX_ALLOC_SIZE environment variables (see [this thread](http://forums.amd.com/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=390&threadid=145052)).

Answer (score 5):

You can query this information at runtime using clGetDeviceInfo and CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE.

See [clGetDeviceInfo Man Page](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) for more information.