# Can I alloc memory bigger than CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE?

Tags: opencl

Can I alloc bigger memory than CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE?

I'm using NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960 (with nvidia driver 352.39 + CUDA 7.5)

GTX960 has 2GB memory, so CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE=512MB (1/4 of full memory as default).

But my kernel needs more memory than 512MB.

Is there some solution to allocate memory bigger than CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE?

Answer (score 2):

You can allocate bigger memory region than CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE, but beware, it should be slow.

Also, read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432659/memory-allocation-nvidia-vs-amd) for more info

Comment: Thank you for reply Citrus.  But I couldn't found how can I allocate bigger memory from your link(and links of link).
Can you tell me what do I have to do?

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. It is not possible to allocate more than the maximum, if you can, it is a flaw in the implementation. Of course you can always allocate multiple buffers of maximum size.

Comment: Just go ahead and allocate multiple memory regions, as @DarkZeros told. But yes, this isn't the most accurate answer, nor recent, I did OpenCL 2 years back, now I use solely DirectCompute (CS_5_0) for everything that needs computing on GPU

Comment: @DarkZeros Well, more precisely, you're not _guaranteed_ to be able to allocate more than MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE. The Khronos docs say that the implementation _may_ return an error if you exceed it. Personally, I've found that Intel's driver does fail when attempting to exceed that amount, while NVidia's doesn't on my setup (everything works happily and I can successfully use the entire buffer on the NVidia card.)